# how to sum the numbers in one row of an array in c++

Tags: c++, arrays

How to sum the numbers in one row of an array in c++
as well how to add all the numbers in the array

I tried many ways and this is the last possibility I can think of.
I am new to programming.

this is the related part of the code to the issue

```
const int NUM_SALESPEOPLE = 4;
const int NUM_PRODUCTS = 3;
const int NUM_TOTALS = 0;

int main()
{

    unsigned __int64 id_numbers[NUM_SALESPEOPLE]; //>>>>> usigned __int64 is used in case the company have id numbers that consest of 10 digits and startr's with a 9
    double sales_amount[NUM_SALESPEOPLE][NUM_PRODUCTS];
    float sales_people[NUM_SALESPEOPLE][NUM_PRODUCTS];
    double sales_total[NUM_SALESPEOPLE][1];
    int total_counter = 0;
    int sales_total_counter = 0;

    //input
    for (int id_counter = 0; id_counter < NUM_SALESPEOPLE; id_counter++)
    {
        cout << "Enter the ID # of Salesperson # " << id_counter + 1 << " :";
        cin >> id_numbers[id_counter];

        for (int sales_counter = 0; sales_counter < NUM_PRODUCTS; sales_counter++)
        {
            cout << "Enter the Dollar value for the Sale of Product # " << sales_counter + 1 << " :";
            cin >> sales_amount[id_counter][sales_counter];
        }
    }

    //Processing

    sales_total[0][1] += sales_amount[0][0];
    sales_total[1][1] += sales_amount[0][1];
    sales_total[2][1] += sales_amount[0][1];


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The example lacks all context. You're adding to different entries, not a single total, and you're reading `sales_amount[0][1]` twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add new row to your 2D array. Try to do like this:

```
void addRow(int array[][MAX], int row, int col, int newRowArray[], int positionToAdd)
{
    for (int i = row; i > positionToAdd); --i)
    {
        for (int j = col; j < col; ++j)
        {
            array[i][positionToAdd]= array[i-1][positionToAdd];
        }
        row++;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < col; ++i)
    {
        array[col][positionToAdd] = newRowArray[i];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What is your array?

Use a for-loop statement to calculate the sum in your array.

```
int array[row][col];
int sum = 0;
for(int i=0; i < col; i++){
    sum += array[index-of-row][i];
}
```

hope this help!

Comment: Thank you so much I will try that out. It is an array of type double. How Can I add one row of the array, as well if you can help me with that.